# @ManagedProperty annotation returns null instead of injecting the property

Tags: jsf-2, annotations, managed-bean

In one sentence: the `@ManagedProperty` annotation does return `null` instead of injecting the property.

The details: there are two classes:

```
@ManagedBean(name="authFilter")
@SessionScoped
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @ManagedProperty("#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean loginBean;
    public void setLoginBean(LoginBean loginBean) {
        this.loginBean = loginBean;
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean  {
    ...
}
```

Now, AFAIK the the `@ManagedProperty` annotation and the setter should be enough for the property to be injected, or at least the other questions here and BalusC's blog suggest this, but it still always remains `null`.

It is also interesting and probably is related to this issue, that I get warnings for these classes that they are already have been registered as a managed bean, even though they only have been registered via the `faces-config.xml` or with the annotataions. (
Tried them booth, separately, no difference.) If none of them is present, then the WARNINGs disappear, but the `@ManagedProperty` does not work ofc.

```
WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'confListBean' has already been registered. Replacing existing managed bean class type <projectname>.web.authFilter with <projectname>.web.authFilter.
```

So the questions would be:

- What else is required for a `@ManagedProperty` to be injected what I am not doing?
- What possibly can 'overregister' these managed beans besides the `@notations` and `faces-config.xml`? Is there a trace for the process which collects the managed beans I could check?

Comment: What about adding a getter for the injected managed-bean ?  I think injecting a session managed-bean into another one with same scope is not a good idea, try to change the scope of "authFilter" to request.

Comment: Do you still any configuration in `faces-config.xml`?

Comment: @Omar Good ideas. I already tried getter earlier, did not make any difference. Although logically it does not make sense, I changed the scope to request, and it did not make any difference.

Comment: @SRy I tried declaring the managed beans either in the `faces-config.xml` or with the `@annotations`, but the property injection did not work. Also, if any of these is used, I get the 'has already been registered' warning at Tomcat startup.

Comment: It turned out, that the problem was not that the injection did not work, but that the bean to be injected was not yet constructed. It is strange, that they are constructed if a value on the GUI is mapped to one of the getters, but not if I try to attach them as a @ManagedProperty and call one of their methods. I'll update the post above to reflect less the problem and more the solution.

Comment: I suppose you use the correct import namespace for `@Sessionscoped`? Also, do you use something that does dependency injection, besides JSF? CDI? Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the loginBean, make sure you set the eager flag to true.

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean", eager=true)
```

This will ensure that the loginBean is created, even if it is not referenced from a GUI element.